# Pull data from array into new array

Tags: ruby

I have the following code. Legislators is an array of data.

`testArray = Legislators.each { |legislator| legislator['name']['first']}`

In powershell this would leave me with an array of the legislator's first names.

Do I need to add each `legislator` object to the `testArray` as I loop through? I feel like there's probably a shortcut...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
testArray = Legislators.map { |legislator| legislator['name']['first'] }
```

`each` only iterates over `legislators` and executes the block; `map` iterates over it and returns an array whose elements are the values of the block.